# WP7 How to debug airplane mode on device?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to debug airplane mode on the device? I tried turning airplane mode on in the device settings and disabling the internet connection on my computer, but NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() still returns true. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice the comment on the bottom of the [official doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable%28v=VS.95%29.aspx):

> This API will always return true on
>   the Windows Phone 7 emulator. Testing
>   therefore requires a facade, mock or
>   conditional chunk of code.

I just tested this on an actual device and indeed, it returns a constant `true`.

However, the thing is - it is all because you keep your phone connected to the PC and the Ethernet interface is available. Once you disconnect the phone and start the app, you will see that a False will be returned.

Comment: Although it also returns true on device (not emulator) when debugging.

Comment: Notice my edit - disconnect the phone from the PC to test the capability.

Comment: For an example of such a interface, check out the NetworkStatusProvider from the WP7 United Nations News app @ http://unitednations.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70986#1461137

Comment: Dennis, I know I can test it when disconnected, but I'd like to be able to debug as well.

Comment: There are some conditions that you can't avoid, and this is one of them. You can debug it manually by using a simple logging mechanism or simply display message boxes with exception data, if any.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that WiFi and/or Bluetooth weren't disabled. This might cause GetIsNetworkAvailable() to return true. According to [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/basics/whats-airplane-mode.aspx):

> While you're in Airplane mode, you can
>   still turn your phone's Wi-Fi and
>   Bluetooth on and off separately.

Maybe the assumption the device is making is that you probably only want to turn of Cellular access automatically, and Bluetooth/WiFi separately.

Comment: Airplane mode is on, wi-fi and bluetooth are turned off, the computer's internet (wi-fi and ethernet) are disabled, but GetIsNetworkAvailable() still returns true.

Comment: because probably GetIsNetworkAvailable()  does not check if you have the internet, it just checks if phone is connected.

Comment: Connected to what? According to MSDN the method returns "true if a network connection is available; otherwise, false." If there is no internet connection, it should return false, and it works as expected when the I'm not debugging on device.

Comment: "How to debug airplane mode on device" "I'm not debugging on device" this is a bit contrary, isn't it? :P

Comment: Not debugging on the device means testing the application in the emulator, which is quite precise when it comes to network connection availability. Therefore the statement was - "works on the emulator but not on the device"

Answer (score 1):

You can check what kind of interface is available:
[NetworkInterfaceType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

```
NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandCdma:
NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandGsm
```

These should be disabled.

Comment: NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType is "None" but NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() still returns true.

Comment: so use this method. It gets more details.

Comment: Those are just enums, not methods/properties