# Airplane mode on is not working

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I want to check for internet availability on my `WP8.1 Emulator` so i turned on the airplane mode and expected that internet would not work but this is not the case internet is working. i am not getting how and why is this happening.

Can anybody help me out in this one.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP7 How to debug airplane mode on device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881907/wp7-how-to-debug-airplane-mode-on-device)

Comment: Did you actually test this in WP7 WP8 and WP8.1?

Comment: I am testing this on WP8.1 Emulator, no device.

Comment: you could simply cut your wifi connection on your pc, then you have no internet anymore

Comment: Emulator will always return `true` for an internet connection apparently

Comment: @loop then please don't tag it incorrectly. People use this as historical documentation for OS problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to cut the internet connection on the emulator, go to the Menu on the right hand side, select `>> Network > Enable Network Simulation`.

Then choose `Network Speed` = `No Network`

Comment: I was going to tell him this so you get a +1. The reason I held back though is because I wasn't sure if AirPlane mode returns the same response as radios on with no network connection.